# Difference between MQQueueConnectionFactory and MQXAQueueConnectionFactory

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

Can someone explain me should i use MQXAQueueConnectionFactory if i want just read messages by @JmsListener in Spring Boot?

I read messages with MQXAQueueConnectionFactory and with MQQueueConnectionFactory and i don't see the difference. If i make exception in listener method i see that message delivered again and again.

In this time setSessionTransacted setting is true and setTransactionManager setting is null for DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory:

```
public void configure(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory,
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    Assert.notNull(factory, "Factory must not be null");
    Assert.notNull(connectionFactory, "ConnectionFactory must not be null");
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setPubSubDomain(this.jmsProperties.isPubSubDomain());
    if (this.transactionManager != null) {
        factory.setTransactionManager(this.transactionManager); // null
    }
    else {
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name suggests, `MQXAQueueConnectionFactory` is used when working with XA transactions. Technically speaking `MQXAQueueConnectionFactory` implements [`javax.jms.XAConnectionFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/XAConnectionFactory.html) which ultimately provides access to the other XA-related [connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/XAConnection.html), [context](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/XAJMSContext.html), [session](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/XASession.html), and [resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/xa/XAResource.html) interfaces. Typically these would be used by the underlying framework (e.g. Java EE or Spring) along with the transaction manager to coordinate your XA transaction between multiple resource managers (e.g. a JMS provider and a JDBC database).

Since you're not working with XA transactions then you should just use `MQQueueConnectionFactory`.

To be clear, an XA transaction is different from a transacted JMS session (which is what you've configured).